# LINQ vs sql - bringing back too many rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert this query

```
select top(10) *
from SOMETABLE
where Name = 'test'
```

into linq so i think it should look like this

```
  var c =
  (from l
  in db.SOMETABLE
  where l.Name= 'test'
  select l).take(10);
```

But when I look into server profiler I can see that linq takes all the data from table and probably apply WHERE and TAKE afer pooling data from database.

The problem is that the SOMETABLE have ~10 000 000 records and it does not work fast.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The `l.Name= 'test'` and `.take` immediately tells me, in 3 different ways, that this is not your actual code. What you are doing *would* work fine (query composition is designed to do what you want), so there is something wrong in your **actual** code. Hence please **show** your *actual* code.

Answer (score 7):

The code you posted has at least 3 mistakes, so I assume it isn't your *actual* code. To get the symptom you describe, the most likely cause is that you have used `IEnumerable<T>` somewhere, and are composing **from that**. To get end-to-end query composition (i.e. to do the `TOP` at the database), you need to be using `IQueryable<T>`. For example, the following is broken:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> data = db.SomeTable;

var c = (from l in data
         where l.Name == "test"
         select l).Take(10);
```

but the following is absolutely fine, noting that only the first line has changed:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> data = db.SomeTable;

var c = (from l in data
         where l.Name == "test"
         select l).Take(10);
```

noting that this is also identical to:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> data = db.SomeTable;

var c = data.Where(l => l.Name == "test").Take(10);
```

So: make sure you haven't forced it to `IEnumerable<T>` (or similar, such as lists) prematurely.

As a final note, IIRC Entity Framework demands an ordering if you are applying skip/take (erroring if you don't) - this further supports my guess that you have dropped to `IEnumerable<T>` too early, but: don't be amazed if you need to specifcy an `order by` too.

Comment: My table was IEnumerable. Thanks!